# Динамический массив строк

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, в чем ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
char* str;
char **ptr;

for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    cin >> str;
    int len = strlen(str); // вычислим длину нашей строки
    ptr[i] = new char[len +1]; // выделим память
    strcpy(ptr[i], str); // скопируем строку str в ptr
}
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    cout  << ptr[i] << endl; // покажем что содержится в ptr
}

delete[] ptr; // освободим выделенную память
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Синтаксис похож на корректный, в чем проблема-то? Что говорит дебаггер? Что попытались сделать Вы?

`cin >> str;` - Вы не выделили память под эту переменную. Определитесь, Вы хотите C++ или Ansi C, и если первое, то лучше используйте std::string, если второе, то сначала выделите память под строку.
Также Вы не выделили память под **ptr, хотя планируете хранить там массив указателей длины 2, память под указатели не выделена.

Comment: @Opium973, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 3):

Минимальные изменения, чтобы код заработал:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
char str[1024];
char **ptr;
const int N = 2;

ptr = new char*[N];

for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    cin >> str;
    int len = strlen(str); // вычислим длину нашей строки
    ptr[i] = new char[len +1]; // выделим память
    strcpy(ptr[i], str); // скопируем строку str в ptr
}
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    cout  << ptr[i] << endl; // покажем что содержится в ptr
}

for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    delete[] ptr[i];
}
delete[] ptr; // освободим выделенную память
return 0;

}
```

Код, который написан по правилам с++ (хотя этот код ещё далек от идеала). Посмотрите, как короче он стал.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<string> ptr;
    const int N = 2;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        ptr.push_back(str);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<ptr.size(); i++) {
        cout  << ptr[i] << endl; // покажем что содержится в ptr
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поскольку у TC программа явно в стиле Си, то можно и так.


Зная, что  размер массива `ptr` известен (N или 2 у TC), то проще выделить память под эти указатели в виде массива.

    char *ptr[N];


а для копирования строки в динамическую память можно воспользоваться функцией `strdup()`

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      cin >> str;
      ptr[i] = strdup(str); // использует malloc, т.о. освобождать надо free()
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      puts(ptr[i]); // намного короче cout << ...
      free(ptr[i]);
    }
    
получая вполне компактный код.

Comment: я пошел по пути "минимальных изменений кода".

Но я знаю, что иногда на чистом си код получается сильно меньше, чем на плюсах.